# Getting Drawable

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am using glide and once the image is retrieved it is put into a view, the view is extended and I use the below code in the constructor. The code returns null. Is there a way to wait until it returns the drawable? It works in the listeners and that's why I am asking if there's a way to wait so it can be in the constructors.

Code:

Glide:

```
Glide
        .with(activity).asBitmap()
        .load(imageURL)
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(currentMap.getWidth(), currentMap.getHeight()) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                currentMap.setUpMap()
                });

            }
```

Drawable in view:

```
drawable = this.getDrawable();
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()' on a null object reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you share your Glide implementation?

Comment: @EugeneH added the glide implementation

Comment: Where are you using "drawable = this.getDrawable();" based on what you are doing, it is setting a BitMap, not a Drawable.

Comment: I use the drawable in the currentmap object that extends a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>` that gives you a drawable:

(`GlideDrawable` is also a `Drawable`).

```
Glide.with(activity)
    .load("...")
    .listener(object : RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable> {
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: GlideDrawable?, model: String?, target: Target<GlideDrawable>?, isFromMemoryCache: Boolean, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

            // GlideDrawable extends Drawable :)
        }

        override fun onException(e: Exception?, model: String?, target: Target<GlideDrawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean = false
    })
```

You will need to remove the `asBitmap()` call.
My code is kotlin because I copy-pasted it from my project, but I believe you can understand it.